# How do I implement RichTextEditor in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking at [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/RichTextEditor.html#includeExamplesSummary) example: and for the life of me I don't see how to utilize this in Flash.  I don't want to build a Flex app... I want to implement this object in my Flash code.  But I'm not having any luck importing mx.controls or getting an instance of this component. It's not in my component's library, either.  Is there some lib I'm missing? Or am I just attempting the impossible here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the one I would go with it is an open source rich text editor.

http://code.google.com/p/as3texteditor/

Answer (score 2):

Flex components/containers must be parented by other Flex components/containers.  Adding one to a regular Flash project won't function properly.

As for Rich Text Editors you have to either build one or look around.  It seems like there's a few non-Flex ones available.  Here's one I found: http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/flashtexteditor/